# Timestamp in SSRS date parameter

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, parameters, timestamp, fetchxml

I am working on an ssrs report with fetchxml as the data source. I have two date parameters in the report. When we provide different dates in from and to parameter , the report works without any issue. But if we provide the same date for both the parameters then the report shows no data. I know that its because of the timestamp. How can i add the timestamp "00.00.01" to the from and "23:59.57" to the to parameter.

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this to your SQL Query in dataset
eg.

```
where somedate between @startDate+' 00:00:00' and @enddate +' 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Is there anyway to add the same in FetchXML?